# roles.remove() function not working in DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

As the title says, `roles.remove()` doesn't work in my code.

```js
const {CommandInteraction} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",

    execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if(!command) {
                interaction.reply({content: "outdated command"});
            }
    
            command.execute(interaction, client);
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1087590559826317353');
            const roleremove = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1087378029073924176');
            return interaction.member.roles
                //.remove(roleremove)
                .add(role)
                .then((member) => 
                    interaction.reply({
                        content: `${role} has been assigned to you.`, 
                        ephermal: true
                    }),
                );
        } else {
            return;
        }
    },
};
```

Right now, the `.remove()` is commented, but when I start the bot, it crashes because `.remove()` function doesn't exist.

I want to make a verification system, in which you can press a button, get a `Verified` role and then lose the `New Player` role.

This is the error message:

```
>  .add(role)
                 ^

TypeError: interaction.member.roles.remove(...).add is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\Events\interactions\interactionCreate.js:20:18)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\Handlers\eventHandler.js:25:63)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\neman\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
```

Comment: Can you post the error message too?

Comment: I updated the text with the error message. @ZsoltMeszaros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, *"interaction.member.roles.remove(...).add is not a function"*, means that `add()` is not a function on the return value of `roles.remove()`.

`roles.remove()` returns a promise. Once it's resolved, you can use the `member` with the updated roles. So you should modify your code like this:

```js
if (interaction.isButton()) {
  const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1087590559826317353');
  const roleremove = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1087378029073924176');

  interaction.member.roles
    .remove(roleremove)
    .then((member) => member.roles.add(role))
    .then((member) =>
      interaction.reply({
        content: `${role} has been assigned to you.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      }),
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```